# VB.NET - Creating variable from header of file

Tags: vb.net, variables, byte

Using Visual Basic.NET
I have a file on the hard drive that I've already confirmed

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path + "\DATA") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Files exist!")
        End Using
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Files missing!")
    End If
```

Now I need to check the first four bytes (header) of the DATA file. They should be XMBF. Can I create a variable from the first four bytes?

```
Dim header as string = 'Data's first four bytes
```

I know the above code wont work (obviously), but

Comment: `IO.File.OpenRead(path + "\DATA")` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Dim header As String = IO.File.OpenRead(path + "\DATA")` 
gives me an error. Please explain?

Comment: You kidding me, right? Did you even glimpse at the link I gave you?

Comment: `IO.File.OpenRead` creates a FileStream object from which you can then read the four bytes...Intellisense and Object Browser will tell you this

Comment: How do I use the `OpenRead` in a message box showing the four bytes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach (comments inline):

```
    Dim fSuccess As Boolean
    Dim fileName As String

    ' Use builtin method to combine two or more directory or file names; this will handle trailing \ correctly
    fileName = IO.Path.Combine(path, "DATA")

    ' Use standard io methods to see if the file exists
    If IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then
        ' Open the file for reading; this opens a FileStream
        Using fs As IO.FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead(fileName)
            ' Declare how much data you want to read
            ' Note that you may need to change this to 8 if the file is expected to be encoded in unicode format
            Const BYTES_TO_READ As Integer = 4

            ' If the file is long enough, then read
            If fs.Length >= BYTES_TO_READ Then
                ' Setup the byte array that you are going to read the data into
                Dim fileData(BYTES_TO_READ - 1) As Byte

                ' Read the number of bytes into the local variable, double-checking to see if you read enough
                If fs.Read(fileData, 0, BYTES_TO_READ) = BYTES_TO_READ Then
                    ' If the bytes that you read 
                    If Convert.ToString(fileData).Equals("XMBF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                        fSuccess = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End Using
    End If

    If fSuccess Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Success")
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine("Failure")
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining everything! I basically copied and pasted what you have here and I'm still getting "failiure" at the end.